# Does the println macro allocate heap memory?

Tags: rust

Does the `println` macro allocate heap memory? I.e. What's the difference (in terms of memory allocation) between calling the `format` macro to create a string to be printed by `println` and just formatting things in the `println` macro?

Comment: [The sources are usually a good place to start looking](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/macros.rs#L147)

Comment: @Sven I don't think that's true. [`print!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/macros.rs.html#115-117) calls [`io::print_`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#801-803), which calls [`stdio::print_to<Stdout>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#771-794), which calls [`Stdout::write_fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/io/stdio.rs.html#532-534), which defers to `StdoutLock::write_fmt`, which is provided in `Write` and calls `fmt::write`, not `fmt::format`. If calling `print!` or `write!` results in a `String` allocation I find that surprising.

Comment: @trentcl You are right -- I misread the code, specifically the call to `format_args_nl!()`. I'm on my phone, so following macro expansions is a bit awkward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `print!`, `write!` and other similar macros that do not return a `String` do not need to allocate memory; they call `format_args!` (which is a compiler built-in) to process the arguments and ultimately use `std::fmt::write` to write data directly to its destination, without preparing a temporary `String`.

Note that this does not mean these macros are unbuffered; in many cases "directly to its destination" means to an intermediate buffer somewhere, not immediately to a file or to stdout. But this buffer may be on the stack and does not need to be reallocated with each call.

Comment: (I'm not sure what I could add to this answer in the way of references... I considered putting links to the implementations of the various functions, as I did in the question comments, but putting that kind of thing in an answer makes me nervous because std will eventually be updated and make it obsolete.)

Comment: You could add links to sources with a specific commit hash on GitHub? And it is maybe worth mentioning that Rust does not guarantee that no heap allocation is happening (AFAIK) but that in the current implementations for main operating systems, no allocation is happening.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is a bit old but want to make a comment and share some of my findings just in case someone else bumped into similar issues as I did.

I think is worth investigating a bit more about all other functions that are called by `println!` macro.
In my case, I am running `rustc 1.64.0-nightly` with the standard library, and I am using custom memory allocator, not the default one that comes with std.

If I run `println!` macro, I can see my allocator called.

```
#.. 0x000055555555ba2b in experiment::allocator::hook () at src/allocator.rs:19
#.. 0x000055555555ba48 in <experiment::allocator::ExperimentalAllocator as core::alloc::global::GlobalAlloc>::alloc (s..=0x555555592011, layout=...) at src/allocator.rs:25
#.. 0x000055555555bad3 in experiment::allocator::_::__rg_alloc (arg0=1024, arg1=1) at src/allocator.rs:10
#.. 0x0000555555572463 in alloc::alloc::alloc () at library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:89
#.. alloc::alloc::Global::alloc_impl () at library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:171
#.. <alloc::alloc::Global as core::alloc::Allocator>::allocate () at library/alloc/src/alloc.rs:231
#.. alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<T,A>::allocate_in () at library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:185
#.. alloc::raw_vec::RawVec<T,A>::with_capacity_in () at library/alloc/src/raw_vec.rs:131
#.. alloc::vec::Vec<T,A>::with_capacity_in () at library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:641
#.. alloc::vec::Vec<T>::with_capacity () at library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:483
#.. std::io::buffered::bufwriter::BufWriter<W>::with_capacity () at library/std/src/io/buffered/bufwriter.rs:115
#.. std::io::buffered::linewriter::LineWriter<W>::with_capacity () at library/std/src/io/buffered/linewriter.rs:109
#.. std::io::buffered::linewriter::LineWriter<W>::new () at library/std/src/io/buffered/linewriter.rs:89
#.. std::io::stdio::stdout::{{closure}} () at library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:607
#.. std::sync::once_lock::OnceLock<T>::get_or_init_pin::{{closure}} () at library/std/src/sync/once_lock.rs:265
#.. std::sync::once::Once::call_once_force::{{closure}} () at library/std/src/sync/once.rs:334
#.. 0x000055555555af3a in std::sync::once::Once::call_inner () at library/std/src/sync/once.rs:434
#.. 0x000055555556ffc2 in std::sync::once::Once::call_once_force () at library/std/src/sync/once.rs:334
#.. std::sync::once_lock::OnceLock<T>::get_or_init_pin () at library/std/src/sync/once_lock.rs:264
#.. std::io::stdio::stdout () at library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:606
#.. std::io::stdio::print_to () at library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:1014
#.. std::io::stdio::_print () at library/std/src/io/stdio.rs:1027
```

So `std::io::stdio::_print` calls `std::io::buffered::linewriter`
Linewriter is trying to get vector with capacity: `alloc::vec::Vec<T>::with_capacity`
And as expected vector alloc will end up in Memory Allocator; in my case, I have my own "ExperimentalAllocator".
This proves that Memory Allocator can be called in some cases indirectly when print macro is being used. The reason why allocator was called is due to `io::buffered` not due to macro implementation. There might be a way not to buffer io, but this is the default option as far as I can see on Linux.

Is also worth mentioning that this does not happen on every call, after LineWriter obtains a vector, it will try to reuse it.

Again when dealing with such issues, source code and debugger are your best friends.
As others mentioned, a lot depends on your setup: especially what rust version are you running.

Hope that may help others bumping into some interesting issues...

Comment: How did you run the `println!` to print you the call stack?